# Reading a text file using thread parallelization

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing

I want to read a text file using threads that needs to work in parallel. I know some things about how to create threads and synchronization (using Interlock and Lock) but i can not read the file using threads in parallel. The problem is, i need to read 4 lines using 4 threads, each reading a different line at the same time. For example;

Thread 1 --- Line 1;

Thread 2 --- Line 2;

Thread 3 --- Line 3;

Thread 4 --- Line 4;

Thread 1 --- Line 5;

Thread 2 --- Line 6; and so on...

The text file contains only positive integers, i.e. each line has 1 positive integer. And the homework wants me to read all the lines, do some math with the numbers and calculate the total time it takes for this. Then, i need to show that the time it takes with parallelization is less than normal sequential reading (no threading).

I tried to do some synchronization but it only allows one thread to read a line at a time and the other 3 are waiting i guess. And the result was already worse than the sequential one.

So, what am i doing wrong? Do i need to study another chapter? If so, can anyone provide me a material for this?

Here is an example code;

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Assignment_2
{
    class Program
    {
        private int line_counter = 2;
        private string path = "C:\\Users\\Asus\\Desktop\\AdvProgTec1\\ws19\\Assignment_2\\Assignment_2\\TOSUM1.DAT";
        private int count = 0; // number of even integers in the list
        private double sum = 0; // sum of those even integers
        private double temp_number;
        private int total_number_of_lines;


        public void Process(object state)
        {
            //string path = "C:\\Users\\Asus\\Desktop\\AdvProgTec1\\ws19\\Assignment_2\\Assignment_2\\TOSUM1.DAT";
            //int count = 0; // number of even integers in the list
            //double sum = 0; // sum of those even integers
            //double temp_number;
            //int total_number_of_lines;

            try
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
                {
                    total_number_of_lines = Convert.ToInt32(sr.ReadLine());
                    //Console.WriteLine("Total number of numbers here: {0}\n", firstLine);

                    while (line_counter <= total_number_of_lines)
                    {
                        lock (this)
                        {
                            temp_number = Convert.ToDouble(sr.ReadLine());
                            Console.WriteLine("{0} here. Readed line: {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.Name, temp_number);
                            if (temp_number % 2 == 0) // If the number is even
                            {
                                sum += temp_number;
                                count++;
                            }
                            line_counter++;
                        }
                        //Interlocked.Increment(ref line_counter);

                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("Sum: {0}, Count: {1}", sum, count);

                    sr.Close();
                }


            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Aborted!!", Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Exiting...", Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
            }

        }  


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p1 = new Program();
            Stopwatch myWatch = new Stopwatch();   

            // START THE PARALLEL THREAD METHOD            
            Thread[] myThreads = { new Thread(p1.Process), new Thread(p1.Process), new Thread(p1.Process), new Thread(p1.Process) };
            int thread_counter = 1;
            myWatch.Start();
            foreach (Thread myThread in myThreads)
            {
                myThread.IsBackground = true;
                myThread.Start();
                myThread.Name = "Thread" + thread_counter.ToString();
                thread_counter++;
                Console.WriteLine("Started thread: {0}", myThread.Name);
                //Thread.Sleep(1);
            }


            foreach (Thread myThread in myThreads)
            {
                myThread.Join();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("All my threads are done.");
            myWatch.Stop();



            Console.WriteLine("Time consumed with Thread method is = {0} msec", myWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
            myWatch.Reset();


            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Then, i need to show that the time it takes with parallelization is less than normal sequential reading (no threading).` It _probably_ won't be less. Seem y comments at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58555831/problem-with-parallel-for-and-parallel-bubble-sort-performance#comment103431663_58555831

Comment: When asking us to comment on your code, it is **critical** that you share a [mcve].

Comment: @jensoncan - for example, have you looked into File.ReadAllLines() https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines -> List<string> -> using Parallel.ForEach process list entries ?

Comment: @yob I suspect `File.ReadLines` may be more appropriate.

Comment: It has to do with the type of your storage. If it's a hard disk you won't get any improvements. If it's an SSD you may double the speed of the reading. While testing take care not to read the same file every time, otherwise you will measure reading from data cached in memory instead of reading directly from the hardware.

Comment: "I want to read a text file using threads that needs to work in parallel." - This will just slow down the reading of the files by a significant (if not huge) amount. Reading with a single thread will be much quicker.

Comment: It's curious that `Process` takes `state` as a parameter, but never uses it. Instead it appears to open the file and read as many lines as the file claims to contain (?!) regardless of which thread `Process` is running in. (Or how long the file actually is.) What part of your code is supposed to pick specific lines from the file for specific threads to process?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils the text file contains nearly 10k lines not just 4. My intention was reading it with 4 threads at the same time.

Comment: @Enigmativity yes, the file contains 10k lines.

Comment: @HABO Ok, i deleted the input parameter state and it made no difference. The idea here is that, threads need to access the lines from the text file as fast as possible, but every line has to be reached only once. You know what i mean? Each thread will get the number from the line and add it to the general sum. The problem is, when i use synchronization, only 1 thread is accessing the text file or i'm doing something wrong

Comment: @jensoncan - I don't understand how your response applies to my comment?

Comment: @Enigmativity you said it will slow down the processor if the text file is not huge. So i said the text file contains 100.000 lines so yes it is a little bit huge (i guess so). So do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @jensoncan - No, I said it would slow down reading of the file by a significant, or possibly huge, amount. I didn't say anything about the file size.